# deploy my project directly without copying always the war file

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm running a web application with `maven + spring mvc + spring data jpa` with `apache tomcat` in eclipse.

I want to deploy my application without opening eclipse and run tomcat inside it, so i have to export my project into `war` and copy it into `apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps` directory and it's working good.

My problem is that i want to work directly into `apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps` with eclipse so like that i don't have to export my `war` file after every changes in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Just configure the Tomcat as server in eclipse and run the project from eclipse.
To configure tomcat in eclipse:
In Eclipse, go to Windows->preferences->Servers->runtime Environment, add tomcat here.

To run the project from eclipse: 
 right click project in Eclipse's project explorer and select->run as->run on server. select the tomcat you configured.

Comment: But i want to run my web application when eclipse is close.

Comment: It is not possible. 
I suggest that you make changes to your code and test the application in eclipse. 
When you are finished with changes, close eclipse, make WAR File and deploy it on server.
If there is some other information you want ask clearly...